# android application update automatically value from parse database

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

How can I update real-time application data from the database ?
For example, I pull out some text from a parse database application and displays it , I want to do that when I change the text in a database it automatically changes in the application.(Without leave and enter the application)
Is that possible?

Comment: have you tried setting a timer which refreshes the app (without animation) every few seconds? it can get expensive in terms of requests especially if your data hasn't been updated. You should look into Pubnub or this: http://attila.tumblr.com/post/21180235691/ios-tutorial-creating-a-chat-room-using-parse-com

Comment: I am developing application for android not for IOS.

Comment: I know, but the concepts are similar. Extract the concept from the code (HINT: read the comments in the code) and apply it to Android

Comment: I do not know how to do it.
You have an example of Android ?